# SQL Server: How to implicitly have all access, and explicitly deny some?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, security, permissions, sql-server-2000

i want to deny some access to some objects in a database for a particular user; but anything not specifically denied i want to, by default, be granted.

Normally i make a user a member of the `db_owner` role, in order to give them all access (this is because the `public` roll doesn't by default have all access). But if i then specifically deny `select` permission, on a specific table, for that specific user, they still have select permission.

How can a user *implicitly* have all access, unless *explicitly* denied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, the issue is not as i described.

- the user is a member of `db_owner` fixed role
- the user is **denied** `select` access to a table
- user can still access table data

This is because the user is first going through a view, stored procedure, or function. Apparently you're allowed to bypass security if you alias the table.

[SQL Server: How to implicitly have all access, and explicitly deny some?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106739/sql-server-how-to-implicitly-have-all-access-and-explicitly-deny-some)

Answer (score 1):

Put everyone in a role that is not an owner like db_datareader. I think your problem was trying to deny select on a db_owner member. Same goes for admins.

Comment: Is the issue that `db_owner` grants `select` permissions - which cannot be denied, while `db_datareader` grants `select` permission which **can** be denied? Can permissions granted by default database roles by denied - except for `db_owner`? Is there a combination of roles that grants everything `db_owner` does, but i **am** allowed to deny?

Comment: Built in roles offer more convenience than flexibility. A member of db_datareader can be individually denied Select on an object.